# I have a code to make a motor run then sleep, then run again, but can't get it to work

Tags: python-3.x, adafruit

I need to make a motor run for an amount of time, sleep for an amount of time, then repeat making an infinite loop

```
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
import time

kit = MotorKit()

while True:
    endtime = time.time() + 60 # runs motor for 60 seconds
    while time.time() < endtime:
            kit.motor1.throttle = 1
            pass
    print('endtime passed')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('done sleeping')
```

I'm expecting the motor to run for a minute, give the `endtime passed` message, and sleep for 10 seconds, but the motor never sleeps. I'm new to python so I don't know much about this and any help is appreciated.

Comment: please fix your indentation first, this code snippet is not very valuable in python...

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation, if not I'm not really sure what else to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the throttle back to 0 before calling `time.sleep`.
`time.sleep` will only pause the process for the given time, you need to explicitly tell the motor to stop moving.

Example:

```py
while True:
    endtime = time.time() + 60 # runs motor for 60 seconds
    while time.time() < endtime:
            kit.motor1.throttle = 1
            pass
    print('endtime passed')
    kit.motor1.throttle = 0
    time.sleep(10)
    print('done sleeping')
```

Also you don't have to busy-wait the 60 seconds the motor is running, you can just set the throttle on the motor and then call `time.sleep`:

```
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
import time

kit = MotorKit()

while True:
    print('running motor')
    kit.motor1.throttle = 1
    time.sleep(60)

    print('pausing 10 seconds')
    kit.motor1.throttle = 0
    time.sleep(10)
    print('done sleeping')
```

Comment: This works! thanks  a lot. one more question though, what would I put in if I want the motor to sleep for 30 minutes?

Comment: @LeviHartman if you want your program to sleep for 30 minutes, you can use `time.sleep(30 * 60)` or `time.sleep(1800)` (1800 seconds = 30 minutes)